# Using Iterator to access different objects inside arraylist

Tags: java

I have a method where I'm trying to use my own iterator to access two different objects in my Collection of game objects. I am first trying to access a foodstation(object) and get it's capacity and store it into fStationCapacity. Then I try and access my Ladybug (Object) and increase it's foodlevel by the fStationCapacity, but I just can't get it because it never reaches the if the statement. How can I try and fix this?

```
public void init() {
    theGameCollection = new GameObjectCollection();
    theGameCollection.add(Ladybug.getLadyBug());
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(210.0,100.0));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(800.5, 200.2));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(364.5, 754.0));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(568.5, 422.5));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(540.0,280.0));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(954.0, 155.2));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(666.0, 689.0));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(489, 900.5));
    theGameCollection.add(new Flag(600.4, 777.5));
    theGameCollection.add(new Spider());
    theGameCollection.add(new Spider());
    theGameCollection.add(new FoodStation());
    theGameCollection.add(new FoodStation());
}   

public void collisionWithFood() {
    IIterator theObjects = theGameCollection.getIterator();
    IIterator theObjects2 = theGameCollection.getIterator();
    int fStationCapacity = 0;
    int foodlevel= 0;
    while (theObjects.hasNext()) {
        GameObject go = (GameObject) theObjects.getNext();
        while (theObjects2.hasNext()) {
            GameObject go2 = (GameObject) theObjects2.getNext();
            if ((go instanceof FoodStation && go2 instanceof Ladybug) && ((FoodStation)go).getCapacity() != 0 ) {
                fStationCapacity = ((FoodStation)go).getCapacity(); //gets the food station capacity and stores into into fStationCapacity
                ((FoodStation)go).reduceCapacity(); //reduces the food station's capacity food level to zero
                ((FoodStation)go).setColor(144, 238, 144); //changes the color of the food station to light green
                ((Ladybug)go2).increaseFoodLevel(fStationCapacity);
                System.out.println("LadyBug has collided with a foodStation of capacity: " + fStationCapacity); 
                System.out.println("Capacity" + fStationCapacity + "\nCurrent Food Level" + foodlevel);
                break; //breaks because I only want one instance
            }
        }       
    }
    theGameCollection.add(new FoodStation()); //creates a new food station with random location and random size
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably theGameCollection.getIterator() always returns the same iterator. instead you should create 2 different iterators for the two loops

Comment: I was confusing myself just needed to have two while loops seperate of each with their own gameobject. I was confusing myself with the foodlevel variable I don't know why I even had it in there it was not needed at all.